# How to find a file recursively and concurrently in all subfolders in bash

Tags: bash, search, recursion, concurrency

I'm wondering how to search all subfolders recursively and concurrently in bash. Script first lists all subdirectories and then goes to each subfolder concurrently. Then, if there are subfolders in a given subdirectory, recursively and concurrently goes to subdireoctories.

I must not use find.

I can write some recursive function that goes to all subfolders but I don't know how to make it concurrent :/

Do you have any idea/clue how to resolve this issue?

Comment: you'll need to illustrate what you mean by concurrent. The only tool that you have to run multiple processes at the same time is to use the `&` at the end of a command. This will run the current command in the background, and then read the next step in the script while the `&`d process continues. Note that this an advanced topic in shell scripting and that if you need your output to be in a certain order, it will be even more complex. Editting your question to include a visual representation of your problem AND then the required output might help you get some support here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function in bash which searches for a file:

```
search_file () # dir fname
{
    local dir="$1" fname="$2" p

    for p in "$dir"/* ; do
        if test -d "$p" ; then 
            search_file "$p" "$fname"
        fi
        if test "$p" = "$dir/$fname" ; then 
            echo "$p"
        fi
    done
}
```

You can also write `if test "${p##*/}" = "$fname" ...` to see if you have found the file.

Comment: Just add `&` after the recursive call to make it concurrent. That requirement is really shady anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but the code seems not to work. It doesn't find any file. Tahnk you, I know how to make it concurrent right now.

Comment: This code doesn't enter in any if statement. It hangs in terminal, and I dont know why. It should work...

Comment: Did you give the two arguments? For instance `search_file . foo.txt`.

Comment: Sure, and it hangs. Have you run it? Does it work on your system?

Comment: Yes, it runs without any trouble. You may trace it using `bash -x search_file . foo.txt`

Comment: Merci. + for p in '"$dir"/*'
+ test /home/kaczka/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/examples/multimedia/video    /qmlvideofx/qml/qmlvideofx/EffectToon.qml = /home/kaczka/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/examples/multimedia/video/qmlvideofx/qml/qmlvideofx/
+ for p in '"$dir"/*'
+ test -d /home/kaczka/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/examples/multimedia/video/qmlvideofx/qml/qmlvideofx/EffectVignette.qml^C It looks like it doesn't take the first argument. It iterates through different folders, as it is shown above.... It cannot even find a file in local folder for example ./script . test.

Comment: Here is an extract + for p in '"$dir"/*'
+ test -d /etc/vmware-tools/messages/zh_CN
+ search_file /etc/vmware-tools/messages/zh_CN ''
+ local dir=/etc/vmware-tools/messages/zh_CN fname= p

Comment: Could anyone help me please. I run the code: ./script /etc host, but it goes to different path !! not to /etc. What am I doing wrong?